# How to have different actions for Navigation Drawer icon and app icon in Action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I have navigation drawer icon as well as app icon on Action bar. I need to have different actions for both (Navigation drawer icon has to open navigation drawer and app icon will start home screen of the app). Right now it looks like the picture below and has the same action for both, app icon and navigation drawer icon.

Thanks a lot for help![image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about how good is it, but got a solution finally!

It can be done using a custom layout for Action bar. Sample code is here.

```
//mActionbarView is the custom view to be used for action bar
    View mActionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);

    Button navDrawer = (Button) mActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.navDrawer);
    Button appIcon = (Button) mActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.appIcon);

    navDrawer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(BaseActivty.this, "Drawer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    });

    appIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(BaseActivty.this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    });

    getActionBar().setCustomView(mActionBarView);
    getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

**custom_action_bar.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/navDrawer"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_drawer"
    android:padding="5dp" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/appIcon"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

what you call NavigationDrawer icon is not actually an icon, it is additional indicator (which is put in ActionBarDrawerToggle) that shows if the Navidation Drawer is opened / closed, so there is only one clickListener that is invoked when clicking on that area.

Even if possible, it would be very confusing for users as that icons are small and close to each other.

consider redesigning your navigation flow in this case (by the way, Back Button should return you back to Home screen from that activity)